# "ПолОг" или "пОлог" — как правильно?

Tags: фонетика

Что-то вдруг меня заело: не могу сообразить, как правильно ставить ударение — "пОлог" или "полОг"?
Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

П**о**лог - это занавеска для кровати, ну, или то, что скрывает (*долину скрывал пОлог тумана*).

Пол**о**г - это краткое прилагательное от пологий. (*берег реки был полОг*).